# How to disable auto scroll in Woocommerce address field on Checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, scroll, checkout, auto

I click the check box for Ship to different address on the Checkout Page in Woocommerce. The address field comes up, and I enter a new street name and number. When finished filling out the field, there is an auto scroll back up to the top of the Billing Address. I scroll back down, fill out the City, click on the next field for State and get another auto scroll to top of Billing Address. Same after I enter a new Zip Code. How can I disable this annoying auto scroll in Woocommerce Checkout?? Thanks so much for checking out my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script in the active theme function.php file

```
add_action('wp_footer','custom_js_function');
function custom_js_function(){
?>
<script>
 jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete( function(event, xhr, settings) {
            if ( jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'woocommerce-checkout' ) || jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'woocommerce-cart' ) ) {
                jQuery( 'html, body' ).stop();
            }
        } );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: `wc_enqueue_js` check it out